# Cannot authorize sql proxy from local machine using credential file to connect to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL from my local windows machine using SQL Proxy.

I am able to connect using authenticated Cloud SDK client:

```
C:\>cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-proj:us-central1:my-instance=tcp:5000
2020/09/10 01:31:50 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5000 for my-proj:us-central1:my-instance
2020/09/10 01:31:50 Ready for new connections
```

However, when I try to connect using a service account and credential file, it fails:

```
C:\>cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-proj:us-central1:my-instance=tcp:5000 -credential_file=C:\credentials.json
2020/09/10 11:12:01 using credential file for authentication; email=svc-acct@my-proj.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2020/09/10 11:12:03 errors parsing config:
        Get https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-proj/instances/my-instance?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: oauth2: cannot fetch token: unexpected EOF
```

Not sure what I am missing here.
Please help.

Comment: Try to add quote around your path name. Check also your credentials.json file with a text editor. The line separator can be in linux mode and not in windows mode.

Comment: I ran your command and worked well for me, I think that your issue is in the `credentials.json`  file, try to re-download the file.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your credentials.json file is invalid. Try generating a new one, and using that instead:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/key.json \
  --iam-account <sa-name>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: @kurtisvg the script works, but do you know how to get this file from the Google Cloud Console by any chance?

Comment: @SamanthaLétourneau this page should help you out: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-console